# Styling NativeBase Inputs

Tags: react-native, native-base

I want to change the border size of an input, the color, etc. For some reason when I stack 2 inputs on top of each other, and I add marginTop to the input underneath, or attempt to resize the inputs, and then center them in the page, the borders on either the left or the bottom disappear.

```
<View style={styles.formAlign}>
    <Item regular style={styles.email}>
        <Input placeholder='Email' />
     </Item>
     <Item regular style={styles.password}>
         <Input placeholder='Password' />
     </Item>
</View>





email:{
   borderWidth:4,
   color:'red'
},
password:{

},
formAlign:{
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center'
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tried your code, modified a bit

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import { Item, Input } from 'native-base';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.formAlign}>
        <Item style={styles.email}>
          <Input placeholder='Email' style={styles.input} />
        </Item>
        <Item style={styles.password}>
          <Input placeholder='Password' style={styles.input} />
        </Item>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  email: {
    width: 300,
  },
  password: {
    width: 300,
    marginTop: 15,
  },
  formAlign: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'blue'
  }
});
```

Got this result

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Nice, I will try that. My work around was to just add borderWidth (top,bottom,left,right) to each input.

Comment: I see. You put the borders on the inputs, not the items. And set the width on the items.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Input
          size="lg"
          colorScheme="gray"
          placeholder="Search"
          variant="filled"
          py="2"
          px="2"
          fontFamily="body"
          style={styles.input}
          borderRadius="20"
          _focus={{
            backgroundColor: "gray.200",
            borderColor: "none",
          }}
          InputLeftElement={
            <Icon
              ml="2"
              size="5"
              color="gray.400"
              as={<Ionicons name="ios-search" />}
            />
          }
        />
```

In case you want to change when focused, I think this might help. Add this as an input attribute.

Comment: Add  a reproductible code

Answer (score -2):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Input, Button, Item, Text, Icon } from 'native-base';

export default class App extends Component{
    render(){
    return(
        <Item rounded style={styles.itemStyle}>
        <Icon active style={styles.iconstyle} name='navigate' />
            <Input keyboardType="default"
                getRef={(input) => this.nameInput = input}
                returnKeyType='next'
                placeholder="Enter Trip Name"
                placeholderTextColor="#FFFFFF"
                style={{ color: '#ffffff' }}
                onSubmitEditing={() => this._focusInput('dayInput')}
                value={this.state.tripName}
                defaultValue={this.state.tripName}
                onChangeText={tripName => this.setState({ tripName })} />
        </Item>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some description too